# To clear the screen and adding the details using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two options as below:

1. Apple
2. Mango

My issues:

1. if I toggle any of the value i.e Apple or mango the screen should clear the previous details which entered.
2. If i select Apple only one tab should enable if i select Mango all the tab should enable

I have 4 tabs in screen `textbox1, Textbox2, Txtbox3, txtbox4`. So to be clear, in `txtbox1` I have select option `Apple & mango`. If I select `apple1` txtbox2 should enable, 3 & 4 should disable. If I select `mango` all txtbox should enable

Comment: Are you using Java or Javascript? They are completely different languages!

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Comment: @sp00m; what, they're both shags?

Comment: I would say 'house' to 'housemate'

Comment: its javascript which i trying

Comment: @user4786572; have you any code, just dump it in the text box, someone will format it for you.#

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function check(){
    if ((document.getElementById("mango").checked = true) && (document.getElementById("mango").checked = true)) {

        document.getElementById("text1").value = " ";

    }
    if(document.getElementById("apple").checked = true){
        alert("ok");

        document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("text3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("text4").disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("mango").checked = true){
    document.getElementById("text1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("text3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("text4").disabled = false;
    }



 }   

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add.html">
   Text1 <input type="text" onclick="check()" id="text1" value="text1"/><br>
   Text2 <input type="text" onclick="check()" id="text2" value="text2"/><br>
   Text3 <input type="text" onclick="check()" id="text3" value="text3"/><br>
   Text4 <input type="text" onclick="check()" id="text4" value="text4"/><br>

  Mango <input type="checkbox" value="mango" id="mango"> 
  Apple <input type="checkbox" value="apple" id="apple">

</form>
```